# getDrawable returns object with 'no properties'

Tags: android, android-drawable, backendless

I'm trying to take a png in my drawable folder, retrieve it, and upload it to my server as a drawable using the Backendless api. However, it does not like this, telling me that it cannot update the object without any properties.

```
I/System.out: fault!
I/System.out: BackendlessFault{ code: '1001', message: 'Cannot update object without any properties: image' }
```

The Code:

```
try {
        Event ne = new Event();
        ne.title = "title of event";
        ne.desc = "short desc";
        ne.extDesc = "long desc";
        ne.image = getDrawable(R.drawable.palestra);
        System.out.println((ne.image != null ? "does" : "does not ") + "work");

        Backendless.Persistence.save(ne, new AsyncCallback<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(Event event) {
                System.out.println("successfull!");
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {
                System.out.println("fault!");
                System.out.println(backendlessFault.toString());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("caught exception! " + e.toString());
    }
```

The purpose of this is to post an example event to the server so that when I pull the Event, with the properties title, desc, extDesc, and image, I can update my onscreen events accordingly. However, I can't seem to take an image I have locally and upload it as a Drawable.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can't use `Drawable` as the object's property in Backendless objects.

Comment: would Bitmap work? If not, what could I use to do what I want to do?

Comment: No built-it class should be used in your objects, since Backendless will try to split it into fields and save as a separate table - I don't think you want additional Drawable or Bitmap table with strange fields. The suggested way is to upload an image to File Service and save only a public URL to it in your data object.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to get the image Bitmap and save it to a file in backendless:

```
        //The outer Backendless call saves the photo in the file and the inner Backendless
    //call saves the object to the table and gives ne.image a String reference
    //to the file path. the column type should be File Reference, saving the path
    //as a String willw ork
    Backendless.Files.Android.upload(mBitmap,
            Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, //compression type
            100, //quality of image
            "mImageName", //What you want to call your file, eg timestamp + "app_image"
            "/my_images", //The path of the file in Backendless
            new AsyncCallback<BackendlessFile>() {

                @Override
                public void handleResponse(BackendlessFile response) {
                    ne.title = "title of event";
                    ne.desc = "short desc";
                    ne.extDesc = "long desc";
                    ne.image = (response.getFileURL());


                    Backendless.Persistence.of(Ids.class).save(ne, new AsyncCallback<Ids>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleResponse(Ids response) {
                        }//end handleResponse

                        @Override
                        public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

                        }//end handleFault
                    });
                }//end handleResponse

                @Override
                public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                }//end handleFault
            });
```

To retrieve the image fromt he url you have saved it to, you have to use an AsyncTask to get the image from the url.

You could create the following class:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

ImageView ivMyImage;
private Bitmap myImage;

public MyAsyncTask(ImageView ivMyImage) {
    this.ivMyImage = ivMyImage;
}//end constructor

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urlString) {

    try {
        URL myImageUrl = new URL(urlString[0]);
        myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myImageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } //end try
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//end catch
    return myImage;
}//end doInBackground

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ivMyImage.setImageBitmap(myImage);

    }//end onPostExecute

}//end class
```

And call the Async task wherever you want to use it with the following code:

```
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(ivMyImage);

myAsyncTask.execute(ne.getImage());//ne.getImage() should retrieve the image url you saved
```

Hope this helps